# Gmail isn't verifying my email address

Tags: email

When I send an email from my domain email to a Gmail account, a question mark appears as the logo and a message that says "Gmail couldn't verify that [domain name] actually sent this message (and not a spammer)"
How do I resolve it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's depends on your site DNS and servers. If you change server, the problem will be solved.

If you send an email from another domain but from same server (DNS) you will still see question mark!

Answer (score 2):

Gmail isn't sure that this the email really is from the domain owner because there is no SPF record on your domain's DNS Zone Editor.

Solutions:

1. To fix this, configure your SPF record to allow the server to send emails. If you are using a dedicated server or VPS, add `ip4:{your_server_ip}` to your SPF record. E.g:

   Edit

   ```
   v=spf1 include:_spf.godaddy.com ~all
   ```

   To

   ```
   v=spf1 ip4:172.1.123.123 include:_spf.godaddy.com ~all
   ```

---

2. This is also common for WordPress users, which I am. WordPress and other apps allow you to configure outgoing email to use SMTP rather than directly from the local server. This solution uses your mail server which typically should already have SPF and other security measures which solves the issue.